# Trying to send audio recorded by Expo to Azure Speech to Text API

Tags: azure, react-native, rest, mobile, expo

I'm trying to send an audio saved by `expo-av` to the `Microsoft Azure speech to text api`, in this function I receive the uri and search for the audio using it in `base64`, after that I transform it into binary with the buffer and then send it in the request .
The answer is always the same, a 200 OK that everything went fine but the displayText, which is the audio recognition property, always comes as an empty string "".
This method send my request:

```js
      const sendToAzure = async (uri) => {
        try {
            const azureEndpoint = 'https://brazilsouth.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=pt-BR';
            const subscriptionKey = 'key';
            const base64 = FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {encoding: "base64"})
            const buffer = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64')
            await axios.post(azureEndpoint, buffer, {
                headers: {
                    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
                },
            }).then(res => console.log(res.data))
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
```

I believe the problem is in the buffer sent, since expo does not have the functionality to read binary files, which requires conversion